# TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found is raised when attempting to print a list

Tags: python, typeerror, indexoutofboundsexception

I am making a simple elevator program where I have to output the makeup of each floor before and after the elevator moves. In order to do that I create a list of the passengers not in the elevator on each floor. The problem arises when I attempt to print this particular list comprised of the passenger's identifications.

I have attempted numerous ways to print a list with a variety of index errors arising such as tuple out of range or this item is not iterable.

```py
interior = [[] for i in range(self._floors)]
for f in range(self._floors): 
    for p in self._passengers:
        if p.waiting() and p.starting_floor() == f:
            interior[f].append(p.getid())
            interior[f].sort()
    print('{passengers:^53}'.format(passengers = ''.join(interior[f])))
```

The expected results are the identifications of the passengers contained in the list. The result is the aforementioned IndexError

Edit: I tried disabling the printing command and am now getting a list index out of range error from append()

Edit2: I converted the starting list to a list comprehension in order for there to be an element corresponding to each floor. Am now getting TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found.

Comment: Check `len(interior)`.

Comment: `interior`contains only one element, an empty list. So you can only access `interior[0]`

Comment: Thierry Lathuille So that means the append is failing if there are no suitable passengers on the first floor?

Comment: Why do you initialize interior like that instead of a simple list?

Comment: Interiors seems like a great use case for `collections.defaultdict`.  Then there's no need to check if a floor has been initialized before accessing it.  `interior = collections.defaultdict(list, {})`

Comment: When asking about code that produces an Exception, always include the complete Traceback in the question. Copy the Traceback and paste it in the question, then format it as code (select it and type ctrl-k)

Comment: @wwii The traceback is referring to this piece of code. I would include it as you have correctly remarked but I doubt it would add anything if I do not include the whole code.

Comment: @KyleParsons How does collections.defaultdict work? Does it remove the need for there to already be an element in place?

Comment: @Triant30 That's correct.  If a you try to access a key of a default dict that has no value, the factory function (in this case `list`) is called with no arguments and set as the value of that key.  Then whatever operation was happening before, continues.  Now this has the downside that accessing your object can mutate it (iteration won't be the same for example), but that may or may not be an issue depending on use.

Comment: The current error is from the `join` method.  It's argument should be an iterable of strings not ints.  You could `''.join(map(str, interior[f]))` instead.

Comment: @KyleParsons Do post it as an answer so I can accept it. Many thanks.

Comment: `p.starting_floor()` -  is `starting_floor` zero based?

Comment: @wwii If by zero based you mean its starting value is zero then no. It starts at 1

Answer (score 0):

`interior` is a list with one element - an empty list.

by accessing it with `interior[f]` you can only access the first element `interior[0]`. So for any floor greater than 0 you will get an error since there is no other elements.

It seems like you would want to change:

```py
interior = [[]]
```

to:

```py
interior = [[] for i in len(self._floors)]
```

This way you will have an empty list for each floor where you can append passengers to.

Comment: @KyleParsons Thanks for that remark. Changed that right away :)

Comment: I am not multiplying though. Would the same happen in the case of a list comprehension where I append items in different indexes of the list?